# TYPO3 "Sorry, you didn't have proper permissions to perform this change."

Tags: mysql, typo3

I have a problem with Typo3.
I can add new pages, folders, etc via pagetree but i can't add, when i trying to do it i getting an error:

`Sorry, you didn't have proper permissions to perform this change.`

and second error in log

```
SQL error: 'Field 'filelink_sorting' doesn't have a default value' (tt_content:NEW) (msg#1.1.12)
```

Error showing when i choose content type (text/image/plugin/etc).

I have installed TemploViola and adding every content from account with admin permissions, on other accounts also getting error.

I found some fixes to it with `ALTER TABLE pages ADD t3ver_swapmode tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0'`
 but nothing changed after execute it in mysql.

Comment: Which version of typo3 are you using?

Comment: Do you run your database in strict mode?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the default definition is missing indeed for the field in TYPO3 6.2-dev LTS.

Please run `ALTER TABLE tt_content MODIFY filelink_sorting tinytext default '' NOT NULL);` in your database administration tool or change the definition at `typo3/sysext/frontend/ext_tables.sql` line 312 accordingly.